# Disk Partitions not visible on Taskbar

Tags: partitioning

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlXGp.jpg)

I am not able to access the contents on my Internal hard disk as the disk partitions are not visible on the taskbar. Please click on the "Reference  Image" for reference. An early answer would be appreciated. 
Note: My PC doesn't have a dual boot. I use Ubuntu as my Primary OS.

Comment: Can you find them opening the second to icon (Files)?

Comment: No They Are not visible in "Files".

Comment: Not even in other location? If so, before anything else, check BIOS/UEFI and confirm the drives are recognized there. If they aren't then it has nothing to do with the OS. Either way, please [edit] your question to add any relevant information. You can then comment to let me know about the updates.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelBay but there's no more relevant information that I can add. I'll check the BIOS/UEFI as you said.

Comment: How about the output of `df -h | grep ^/`? I am not really sure what we are supposed to see on the reference image, it looks ok. The task bar never had disk partitions, so it's not surprising.

Comment: @mikehatever The otuput of df -h | grep ^/ is this:                                                    /dev/sda6       191G  6.0G  175G   4% /

Comment: Also @mikewhatever the reference image is not ok. While installing Ubuntu I partitioned my 1tb hard disk into 3 parts, one of 208 gb, one of 315 and last one of 416 gb. The 208 gb partition houses the ubuntu installation while the rest two are for storing personal data. In the reference image under the audacious Icon, there used to be 2 drives which are not there now.

Comment: check nautilus to see if automount has been turned off

Comment: Can you tell me in Detail about Nautilus @ravery ?

Comment: not in detail, I use a different desktop, but in nautilus (the file manager) there should be a settingn for automount. Also if the partitions were added to fstab for mounting at boot they won't show as devices any more because they are in the files system

Comment: Alright, we need to figure out what partition you really have, so you need to either post a screenshot of Gparted instead of the "reference image", or the output of  `sudo parted -l`. Please add either/or to the question.

Comment: Well thanks everyone for your suggestions but I chose the easiest way instead. I formatted my hard Disk and did a fresh install of ubuntu.